# How to keep the button in place in android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have four buttons at the button of the screen and I want to keep the gaps between them as equal as possible.

[image]
This is how I place the buttons .

[image]
This is how they show up while I run it on emulator and the device.

Here's my xml code for the buttons.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_base"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/base" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_gotoLocation"
            android:layout_width="43dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/location" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate"
            android:layout_width="43dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
            android:background="@drawable/cal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_info"
            android:layout_width="43dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calculate"
            android:background="@drawable/info" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_place"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_info"
            android:src="@drawable/add_place" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: in the xml there are 3 buttons.. right?

Comment: Is this your full layout file code ?

Comment: umm yes. I use one imageview as a dialog button in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use android:layout:weight

UPdate:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_base"
        android:layout_width="43dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gotoLocation"
        android:layout_width="43dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="43dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_info"
        android:layout_width="43dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_place"
        android:layout_width="43dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: when you are using weight then height or width must be 0px.

Comment: @PiyushGupta its not necessary. It may have problem if we all drawbles are not same in size. So defining a width in horizontal is safe move

Comment: its just for example.. we are using drawable here. so better to give fix width and height... 0dip will be better option if user is confident about is images which is used as background.. I am not saying you wrong but I have given the answer as user requires

Comment: if I add weight , all the buttons are stretched no matter what height and width size I use

Comment: u r the best Mayuri . It works perfect and exactly what I want . Thanks for ur help . I appreciate this :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a Linear Layout and have the weight of the item set to 1...

```
<LinearLayout android:weight="1">
     <Button android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <Button android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <Button android:layout_weight="1"/>
     <Button android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="bottom"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_base"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/base" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gotoLocation"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/location" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_info"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/add_place" />
 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give same `android:layout_marginLeft` value for all buttons.

Answer (score 0):

OK you can try this

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity:"center_horizontal|bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_base"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/base" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gotoLocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/location" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/cal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/calculate"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_place"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_info"
        android:src="@drawable/add_place" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Just ignore the margins and it should fill well.

Hope it works.